# symbolic matlab matrix to latex

Tags: matlab, latex, indices

Consider the symbolic matlab expression

`e = (a_1_1 + a_2_2)*(b_1_1 + b_2_2)`

Using `latex(e)` this yields

`\left({{a_{1}}}_{1} + {{a_{2}}}_{2}\right)\, \left({{b_{1}}}_{1} + {{b_{2}}}_{2}\right)`

Is it possible to [somehow] use comma as separator between the indices, i.e. to get

`\left(a_{1,1} + a_{2,2} \right)\,\left(b_{1,1} + b_{2,2}\right)`

Answer (score 0):

I'd be interested in an easy way to do it.  An ugly way would be:

```
eqn = latex(e);
eqn1 = regexprep(eqn,'{{','');
eqn2 = regexprep(eqn1,'}}}_{',',');
```